# package sun.awt.windows does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When building maven project getting package sun.awt.windows does not exist when using java 11

**sun.awt.windows with JDK8 works with IntelliJ**

**sun.awt.windows with OpenJDK11 does NOT work with IntelliJ**

I Disable the Use '--release' option... in intellij but it still did not work

My project has three modules in it

please help someone to resolve the issue

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (GitHub project link would be fine).

Comment: @AzmatHayat Did you have a chance to prepare a reproduction?

Comment: @AzmatHayat Do you have any updates?